# Open Splash Activity always when App starts in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to open Splash Activity always when I press Home button and then open my app again? In the sense

Open my App... do what ever required in the some screen...and then I press home button on the phone open a different app and then I open my app I would like it open the splash activity instead of where I left?

I am using fragment... always!

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, onPause() is called when you press the home button.
onResume() is called when you come back from home.

Put the code to show the splash screen in these methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is that `onStop()` will be called for any of your activities that is not longer being seen by this user.  This includes when they go back to the home screen, or they select a notification that launches a different app on top of yours, or any number of other possibilities.  You can't really know from `onStop()` what the user did to make it become invisible, or if something else forced it.

That said, if you want to start over from the default main activity on every launch, you can simply `finish()` *every* activity during its `onStop()` so that the user can't possibly return to it.  The user will never have an active task stack, so they will have to start over from the beginning every time.

Be aware that your users may find that this to be a disturbing user experience and not match their expectations how Android apps normally behave.